# Embed Flash player in a PHP page for live streaming

Tags: html, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

I want to play live RTMP streaming video in my PHP application. I have tried the code below for that purpose:

```
<object width="400" height="409" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
  <param name="SRC" value="rtmp://111.111.11.1/live">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="rtmp://111.111.11.1/live" width="400" height="409"></embed>
</object>
```

But it is not working. When I replace **rtmp://111.111.11.1/live** with some 3gp files, then the code is working. What is the problem here? Is there any other code to play live streaming video?

**Note:** rtmp://111.111.11.1/live is a sample URL.

Comment: And how this question is related to php, html5. It look like simple running rtmp url to a html object through like swf play.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj dO  you have some solution for above question?

Comment: Don't know but if this url can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521588/any-free-flash-video-player-than-can-play-rtmp-stream